# Most up to date CSS compliance table for email clients

Tags: html, email, html-email

I've found this CSS compliance table for **email clients**:

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

**Are there any improvements?** (last update there is dated 2013)

**Can somebody point to to most up to date table of CSS compliance for email clients?**

Comment: It hasn't changed a whole lot since then but mailchimp seem to keep their version updated: http://kb.mailchimp.com/campaigns/ways-to-build/css-in-html-email (use the links on the right)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by Pete in the comment, Mailchimp has it's own compliancy table, that can be found here:

http://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/email-client-css-support/